# Dual GPU (Nvidia + ASPEED) extended desktop configuration help Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, multiple-monitors, nvidia-settings

I can't seem to find the answer to my configuration problem. 
I have 2 graphic cards, one on the motherboard (aspeed) and one on PCI-E (Nvidia).

```
lspci | grep VGA
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 30)
```

both are recognized as providers by xrand:

```
xrandr --listproviders          
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x1e3 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x41 cap: 0x0 crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

BUT, the onboard GPU does not display anything past the boot process, I don't have access to it in the "Display" tool to configure screens, nor in the Nvidia X Server Settings (see screenshots)
Moreover, if I switch tty (say with Ctrl+Alt+F3 for example), then the onboard GPU is the one that gets activated (consistent with the fact that the OS boots on it).

How to I get my desktop to extend to the second GPU (and 4th screen) ? How to I get Ubuntu to add that GPU to my current X server ?

Thanks!

PS: I don't have a xorg.conf, I only have xorg.conf.05192016  xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original and xorg.conf.backup, and whenever I make a xorg.conf, it disappears at next reboot.

[image: Display configuration Nvidia]
[image: GPU configuration Nvidia]

Comment: No one to help ? :sadness:

Answer (score 1):

Here is why:

Aspeed is your onboard GPU, whose driver is not provided by Nvidia. Thus, it not showing up in your Nvidia X server settings should be expected.

Comment: Oh I see ! Any idea how I could get it to show up there ? ?

Comment: Umm I am not so sure - maybe you can't since it is technically managed by Intel?